# Calculate enclosing rectangle of a given aspect ratio

Tags: aspect-ratio

Given the height and the width of a rectangle of any size and an aspect ratio, how can I calculate the height and width of a minimum enclosing rectangle of the given aspect ratio?

In code, the function signature would look like this

```
public Size getMinimumEnclosingRectangle(Size originalRectangle, float aspectNumerator, float aspectDenomiator);
```

Calls to this function would look like

```
originalRectangle    AspectRatio     Result
-------------------------------------------
100x100              1:2             100x200
64x32                1:1             64x64
125x100              3:2             150x100
100x345              1:3             115x345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but the way I do this calculation is to calculate the change in aspect ratio and then base the resulting width/height calculation of of that. Here is some code to illustrate this algorithm in practice:

```js
var sourceImages = [
 {width: 100, height: 100, toAspectRatio:1/2  },
 {width: 64,  height: 32,  toAspectRatio:1/1  },
 {width: 125, height: 100, toAspectRatio:3/2  },
 {width: 100, height: 345, toAspectRatio:1/3 },
 {width: 345, height: 100, toAspectRatio:1/3 }
];


function calculateNewSize( sourceWidth, sourceHeight, toAspectRatio )
{
 var aspectRatioChange = (sourceWidth / sourceHeight) / toAspectRatio;
 var fitWidth = aspectRatioChange < 1 ? sourceHeight * toAspectRatio : sourceWidth;
 var fitHeight = aspectRatioChange >= 1 ? sourceWidth / toAspectRatio : sourceHeight;

 console.log('(' + aspectRatioChange + ') ' + sourceWidth + " x " + sourceHeight + " -> " 
    + toAspectRatio + ' -> ' + fitWidth + ' x ' + fitHeight); 
}

sourceImages.forEach(function(source) {
 calculateNewSize(source.width, source.height, source.toAspectRatio);
});
```